# Is there a way to make Chrome assume a domain's certificate is valid (in other words, skip validating its certificate)?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, ssl, certificate, https

Is there a way to make Chrome on Windows avoid validating the certificate for a domain such as (`www.foo.com`):

[image: Identity not verified]

Basically I want to avoid getting this warning message for that site every time I start Chrome:

[image: Certificate Warning]

Comment: you forgot to block the domain name in the middle of the top image. [EDIT] Fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

You can import the server's certificate (or the certificate of the CA that signed the server's cert, if it's not self-signed) into Windows' certificate store (which Chrome and IE use; Firefox has its own). Trusting the server's own cert should work only for that certificate. Trusting the CA is risky, as any CA that you trust can sign a certificate for any site, so you're essentially granting the owner of the CA cert the ability to man-in-the-middle any TLS traffic (except on sites that use pinning, such as Google properties in Chrome) undetectably.

Click on `Certificate information` and there should be an option to import the certificate, or to save it to a file. Saved certificates can be opened and imported by Windows.